# Get value in map for known hash output

Tags: c++, hash

I have an `std::unordered_map` `myMap` with key, value pairs of `<Key*, Value>`. `Key` is defined as so:

```
struct Key
{
    unsigned long int UniqueValue;
    unsigned long int NonnUniqueValue;
}
```

The rest of the program ensures that `UniqueValue` is unique for every instance of `Key`, however `NonUniqueValue` can be different between keys. My hash function is then defined as:

```
struct KeyHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
    {
        return k.UniqueValue;
    }
}
```

and my map is then:

```
std::unordered_map<Key*, Value, KeyHash> myMap;
```

So, basically, each key already knows it's own hash value. I want to be able to reference the key, value pair by both the `Key` instance itself and the `UniqueValue`. Since the hash value is already known, can I use this to directly reference value?

For instance, if I have two instances of `Key` `k1` and `k2` where `k1.UniqueValue = 2`, `k2.UniqueValue = 5`, `k1.NonUniqueValue = 42`, and `k2.NonUniqueValue = 42`, I want to be able to reference the value in `myMap` with key `k1` knowing only `k1.UniqueValue`.

Is this possible to do without directly modifying `Key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a minor point.  The way you declared your container:

`std::unordered_map<Key*, Value, KeyHash> myMap`

makes the map key to be a *pointer* to `Key` structure, rather than a value.

Now, the simplest way to do what you need is to reorganize your hash table:

`std::unordered_map<
    unsigned int /*unique_part_of_key*/,
    std::pair<unsigned int /*non_unique_part_of_key*/, Value>>`

To do precisely what you're asking, you'll need to add a custom KeyEqual predicate that ignores the non-unique part of the key, like your KeyHash does.  Then, you could create a fake instance of a Key, with a random non-unique value, and use it to retrieve the reference you need:

`struct KeyEqual
{
    bool operator(const Key& k1, const Key& k2) const
    { return k1.UniqueValue == k2.UniqueValue; }
};
std::unordered_map<Key*, Value, KeyHash, KeyEqual> myMap{KeyHash(), KeyEqual()};`